# Expectation of the product of mean independent random variables

Tags: probability, expected-value

I have random variables $a$ and $b$, which are such that $\mathbb{E}[a|b]=0$. I am trying to compute $E[ab]$. Is the following correct? $$\mathbb{E}[ab]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[ab|b]]=\mathbb{E}[b\mathbb{E}[a|b]]=\mathbb{E}[b(0)]=0$$

Where I have used the law of iterated expectations. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you meant to show, could you elaborate..? What does $b(0)$ mean here?

Comment: @Tim I mean to show that $\mathbb{E}[ab]=0$.

Comment: This is correct  but you don't have to write double expectations and $b(0)$ should be $b \times 0$